# help with my chapters spacing

Tags: spacing, header-footer, chapters

I have been trying and trying even using this forum to fix a problem that I have been facing and I don't know how to fix it...

[image]

My code for this and so on is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} % setting      pages 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\linespread{2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}



\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{firstauthoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

        \Huge
        \textbf{Thesis Title}

        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \LARGE
        Thesis Subtitle

        \vspace{1.5cm}

        \textbf{}

        \vfill


        \vspace{0.8cm}

        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{logo.png}

        \Large
        Department of \\
        College of Arts and Sciences\\
        University of \\
        Date

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction}


\chapter{Materials and Methods}
\input{chapters/chapter02}


\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{refer}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

If someone could clarify how to change that I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to move titles up or strech space between titles or what?

Comment: I need "Chapter 2" to go up bc there's too much spacing

Comment: `Titlesec` is your friend for such a job.

Comment: I found a bunch of things talking about that and also tried changing 50pt to 20pt to 10pt and it didn't change anything

Comment: There's no accounting for  taste, but there is much vertical space in part because you are using `\linespread{2}` (excessive except to correct  printed drafts at hand) and in part because chapters need enough space around to highlight it. The second part is not really a problem, it's just that we're too used to the poor typography of word processors. Said that, for the nonconformists: topic  [headings](https://www.ctan.org/topic/headings) and [memoirchapterstyles examples](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoirchapterstyles) in CTAN.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible solution using  `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} % setting      pages 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\linespread{2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{firstauthoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}


\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{1.8ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.0ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.8ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.0ex plus .2ex}

 \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

        \Huge
        \textbf{Thesis Title}

        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \LARGE
        Thesis Subtitle

        \vspace{1.5cm}

        \textbf{}

        \vfill


        \vspace{0.8cm}

%        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{logo.png}

        \Large
        Department of \\
        College of Arts and Sciences\\
        University of \\
        Date

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
%\input{chapters/introduction}


\chapter{Materials and Methods}
%\input{chapters/chapter02}

%
%\bibliographystyle{chicago}
%\bibliography{refer}
%
%\appendix

\end{document}
```

Produce:
[image]

where spaces are controlled with: `\titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}`